# Installation of Soot plug-in on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, compiler-optimization, soot

I tried to install Soot 2..5.2 plugin on Eclipse Kepler using  Help->Install New Software.. and then using the link http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/eclipse/updates/ but it displays "Unable to read repository at http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/eclipse/updates/". How do I install soot plugin on Eclipse Kepler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong update site. According to [this Soot wiki page](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Eclipse-Plugin-Installation#eclipse-update-site), the correct update site URL is  `http://sable.github.io/soot/eclipse/`

Comment: This location is not available anymore and no updates are published on the wiki.